# Using image_tag helper without src attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lazy-loading

This may be a very simple question, but how do I rewrite this in Ruby?

`<a href="https://yourlinkhere.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img data-lazy="<%= image_path("assets/images/your-image.png") %>" alt="logo" /></a>`

I originally had it written this way (see below), until I needed to remove the `src` attribute from the img tag and replace it with `data-lazy` to take advantage of Slick's lazy-loading feature — that's where I'm getting hung up with the `image_tag` helper:

`<%= link_to image_tag("assets/images/your-image.png", alt: "logo"), "https://yourlinkhere.com/", target: "_blank", rel: "noopener noreferrer" %>`

I'm wondering if I have to use `image_path` instead of `image_tag` here because I'm not including an src attribute... unless there's a way to use the `image_tag` helper and NOT include an src?

Thank you! I don't work with Ruby on Rails typically, but I've been learning it for a project that I work on as the frontend dev. Stumped here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code of `image_tag` I was surprised that it seems to be impossible to use this method to generate `img` tags without an `src` attribute. But then I realized that the `src` attribute is required for `img` tags by the [HTML specification](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp).

Therefore I think your best option is to generate an `img` tag with an empty `src` value if that is supported by your lazy loading library.

```
<%= link_to(
      image_tag('', alt: 'logo', data: { lazy: image_path('your-image.png') }), 
      'https://yourlinkhere.com/', 
      rel: 'noopener noreferrer', target: '_blank'
    ) %>
```

When you do not care about invalid HTML then you might consider writing the `img` tag manually by using the block syntax of `link_to`.

```
<%= link_to(
      'https://yourlinkhere.com/', 
      rel: 'noopener noreferrer', target: '_blank') do %>
  <img alt="logo" data-lazy="<%= image_path('your-image.png') %>" />
<% end %>
```

Comment: This 100 percent works. Thank you, @spickermann! It seemed like there wasn't a way to generate an `img` tag without an `src` attribute using the `image_tag` helper and I guess I was right! But keeping empty `src` value totally works with Slick's library, so it's a great semantically valid fix.